# How to rewritecond urls from folder?

Tags: .htaccess

How to rewrite all requests

FROM **/folder1/folder2/%any-request or page%** 
TO **/folder1/folder2/index.php**

I cant understand how to exclude other urls from rule..

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ folder1/folder2/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` are a bit off.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/.*$ folder1/folder2/index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule with negative lookahead regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(folder1/folder2)/(?!index\.php).*$ $1/index.php [NC,L]
```